# how to check the normality of data on a column grouped by an index

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

i'm working on a dataset which represents the completion time of some activities performed in some processes. There are just 6 types of activities that repeat themselves throughout all the dataset and that are described by a numerical value. The example dataset is as follows:

```
name duration
1    10
2    12
3    34
4    89
5    44
6    23
1    15
2    12
3    39
4    67
5    47
6    13
```

I'm trying to check if the duration of the activity is normally distributed with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import normaltest

measurements = df['duration']
stats.probplot(measurements, dist='norm', plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
ax = sns.distplot(measurements)
stat,p = normaltest(measurements)

print('stat=%.3f, p=%.3f\n' % (stat, p))
if p > 0.05:
  print('probably gaussian')
else:
  print('probably non gaussian')
```

But i want to do it for each type of activity, which means applying the stats.probplot(), sns.distplot() and the normaltest() to each group of activities (e.g. checking if all the activities called 1 have a duration which is normally distributed).

Any idea on how can i specify in the functions to return different plots for each group of activities?

Comment: Does your dataset have at least 8 samples per each type of activity? Can I assume that the above is just a sample of your dataset?

Comment: @MichaelS. yes, it has 26 samples. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that you have at least 8 samples per activity (as `normaltest` will throw an error if you don't) then you can loop through your data based on the unique activity values. You'll have to place `pylab.show` at the end of each graph so that they are not added to each other:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns

import random                        # Only needed by me to create a mock dataframe
import warnings                      # "distplot" is depricated. Look into using "displot"... in the meantime
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')    # I got sick of seeing the warning so I muted it

name = [1,2,3,4,5,6]*8
duration = [random.choice(range(0,100)) for _ in range(8*6)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":name, "duration":duration})

for name in df.name.unique():
    nameDF = df[df.name.eq(name)]
    measurements = nameDF['duration']
    stats.probplot(measurements, dist='norm', plot=pylab)
    pylab.show()
    ax = sns.distplot(measurements)
    ax.set_title(f'Name: {name}')
    pylab.show()
    
    stat,p = normaltest(measurements)
    print('stat=%.3f, p=%.3f\n' % (stat, p))
    if p > 0.05:
        print('probably gaussian')
    else:
        print('probably non gaussian')
```

[image]
[image]

.
.
.
etc.